# Slow query in SSD when enable_bitmapscan=on

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, execution-plan

Table INFO and index INFO:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PART (

    P_PARTKEY       SERIAL,
    P_NAME          VARCHAR(55),
    P_MFGR          CHAR(25),
    P_BRAND         CHAR(10),
    P_TYPE          VARCHAR(25),
    P_SIZE          INTEGER,
    P_CONTAINER     CHAR(10),
    P_RETAILPRICE   DECIMAL,
    P_COMMENT       VARCHAR(23)
);

CREATE TABLE LINEITEM (
    L_ORDERKEY      INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    L_PARTKEY       INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    L_SUPPKEY       INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    L_LINENUMBER    INTEGER,
    L_QUANTITY      DECIMAL,
    L_EXTENDEDPRICE DECIMAL,
    L_DISCOUNT      DECIMAL,
    L_TAX           DECIMAL,
    L_RETURNFLAG    CHAR(1),
    L_LINESTATUS    CHAR(1),
    L_SHIPDATE      DATE,
    L_COMMITDATE    DATE,
    L_RECEIPTDATE   DATE,
    L_SHIPINSTRUCT  CHAR(25),
    L_SHIPMODE      CHAR(10),
    L_COMMENT       VARCHAR(44)
);
```

```sql
CREATE INDEX IDX_LINEITEM_ORDERKEY ON LINEITEM (L_ORDERKEY);
CREATE INDEX IDX_LINEITEM_PART_SUPP ON LINEITEM (L_PARTKEY,L_SUPPKEY);
```

#### Symptom

Executing the query get slower when `enable_bitmapscan=on`, it takes **16 seconds**. However, when `enable_bitmapscan=off`, it only takes **9 seconds**.

```sql
select
   100.00 * sum(case
      when p_type like 'PROMO%'
         then l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)
      else 0
   end) / sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) as promo_revenue
from
   lineitem,
   part
where
   l_partkey = p_partkey
   and l_shipdate >= date '1997-12-01'
   and l_shipdate < date '1997-12-01' + interval '1' month
LIMIT 1;
```

With `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`(`enable_bitmapscan=on`), it shows the bottleneck is `Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan`.

```sql
Limit  (cost=1563376.53..1563376.54 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=14141.250..14242.134 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Finalize Aggregate  (cost=1563376.53..1563376.54 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=13479.594..13580.478 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Gather  (cost=1563376.29..1563376.50 rows=2 width=64) (actual time=13478.519..13580.466 rows=3 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=1562376.29..1562376.30 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=13460.485..13460.487 rows=1 loops=3)
                     ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=84543.57..1556948.00 rows=310188 width=33) (actual time=13323.848..13387.951 rows=257261 loops=3)
                           Hash Cond: (lineitem.l_partkey = part.p_partkey)

                           ##################################
                           ####  WHERE THE SLOW HAPPENS  ####
                           ##################################
                           ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on lineitem  (cost=19115.18..1481372.36 rows=310188 width=20) (actual time=72.569..12935.065 rows=257261 loops=3)
                                 Recheck Cond: ((l_shipdate >= '1997-12-01'::date) AND (l_shipdate < '1998-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                 Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5798979
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=18882 lossy=121916

                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_lineitem_shipdate  (cost=0.00..18929.06 rows=744450 width=0) (actual time=64.634..64.634 rows=771784 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((l_shipdate >= '1997-12-01'::date) AND (l_shipdate < '1998-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))

                           ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=49314.51..49314.51 rows=833351 width=25) (actual time=298.333..298.334 rows=666667 loops=3)
                                 Buckets: 65536  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 2432kB
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on part  (cost=0.00..49314.51 rows=833351 width=25) (actual time=107.366..213.265 rows=666667 loops=3)
                                 
 Planning Time: 8.655 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 45
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: ... Total 983.466 ms
 Execution Time: 16207.298 ms
```

With `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`(`enable_bitmapscan=off`), the `Bitmap Index Scan + Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan` is replaced by `Seq Scan`, which has **7 seconds** in difference.

```sql
 Limit  (cost=1671904.47..1671904.48 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=7177.284..7260.452 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Finalize Aggregate  (cost=1671904.47..1671904.48 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=6565.868..6649.035 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Gather  (cost=1671904.23..1671904.44 rows=2 width=64) (actual time=6565.253..6649.024 rows=3 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=1670904.23..1670904.24 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=6548.223..6548.252 rows=1 loops=3)
                     ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=65428.40..1665475.94 rows=310188 width=33) (actual time=6410.218..6475.825 rows=257261 loops=3)
                           Hash Cond: (lineitem.l_partkey = part.p_partkey)

                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on lineitem  (cost=0.00..1589900.30 rows=310188 width=20) (actual time=0.294..6044.430 rows=257261 loops=3)
                                 Filter: ((l_shipdate >= '1997-12-01'::date) AND (l_shipdate < '1998-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 19738089

                           ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=49314.51..49314.51 rows=833351 width=25) (actual time=311.963..311.963 rows=666667 loops=3)
                                 Buckets: 65536  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 2464kB
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on part  (cost=0.00..49314.51 rows=833351 width=25) (actual time=105.028..220.460 rows=666667 loops=3)
 Planning Time: 8.637 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 45
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: ... 927.562 ms
 Execution Time: 9290.835 ms
```

Storage Device: `WD SN-850 500G NVMe SSD`. I noticed that in HDD, this huge difference (9 vs 16) does not appears (the two query plans are same in HDD). I am using `PostgreSQL 12` on ubuntu 21.

#### Question

Why does the big performance difference appears? Do I need to provide more information to confirm the root cause?

Comment: What are the values for `random_page_cost` and `seq_page_cost`?

Comment: If you increase `work_mem`, does the query speed improve?

Comment: If you want to compare to HDD in any meaningful way, you need to show the plans for that one as well.  Also, turn on track_io_timing and do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` rather than just `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.